# How to get Pipeline created by playbin in textual format in Gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, mpeg, mpeg2-ts, playbin2

I'm playing a transport stream file (*.ts) using the following pipeline:

```
gst-launch-0.10 playbin2 uri=file:///c:/bbb.ts
```

But I need to convert that into a pipeline myself. I'm not sure how to achieve this.

So far I have tried: (works fine)

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=c:/bbb.ts ! tsdemux ! audio/x-ac3 ! fakesink
```

But if i replace fakesink with autoaudiosink it fails with a not-linked error.

And even the fakesink doesn't work for video:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=c:/bbb.ts ! tsdemux ! video/x-mpeg2 ! fakesink
```

So I have two questions:

1. How to find out pipeline created by playbin element.
2. How to play mpeg2-ts file using gstreamer pipeline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer to question 1 -

There is a way to get the graphs of the pipeline created mentioned in documentation of [basic tutorial-11](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorial+11%3a+Debugging+tools).

A brief from the page

> **Getting pipeline graphs**
>
> For those cases where your pipeline starts to grow too large and you
>   lose track of what is connected with what, GStreamer has the
>   capability to output graph files. These are .dot files, readable with
>   free programs like [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/), that describe the topology of your
>   pipeline, along with the caps negotiated in each link.
>
> *This is also very handy when using all-in-one elements like [playbin2](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/2012.5/gst-plugins-base-plugins-0.10/gst-plugins-base-plugins-playbin2.html#playbin2) 
>   or [uridecodebin](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/2012.5/gst-plugins-base-plugins-0.10/gst-plugins-base-plugins-uridecodebin.html#uridecodebin), which instantiate several elements inside them*.

I hope this resolves what you want